# How to fix Bioconductor EnrichKEGG with Expected input gene ID error?

Tags: r, bioconductor, transcription

I am trying EnrichKEGG on a few gene samples of genes to check it works before inputting the full genome:
This is my data input as test.csv

| id | fc |
| --- | --- |
| AJAP_14870 | -0.04 |
| AJAP_14875 | 0.32 |
| AJAP_14880 | -0.06 |
| AJAP_14885 | 0.15 |
| AJAP_14890 | -0.52 |
| AJAP_14895 | -0.39 |
| AJAP_14900 | 0.16 |

````
> geneList = test[,2]
> names(geneList) = as.character(test[,1])
> geneList = sort(geneList, decreasing = TRUE)


> data(geneList, package="DOSE")
> gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
> 
> kk <- enrichKEGG(gene         = gene,
+                  organism     = 'aja',
+                  pvalueCutoff = 0.05)```
````

There are no spaces in the gene names, I tested via

````
print(head(test$ID), quote=TRUE)```
````

But I get the error

````
--> No gene can be mapped....
--> Expected input gene ID: AJAP_00520,AJAP_18610,AJAP_35690,AJAP_40945,AJAP_06465,AJAP_09250
--> return NULL...```
````

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove `data(geneList, package="DOSE")` line.

This line is loading the sample data named `geneList` from the package `DOSE`and hence replacing the genelist you want to analyze.

Comment: Hi! I'm so sorry this response is so late - I've just come back to this analysis. Thanks so much for your help. Now when I run the code I get: 

> kk <- enrichKEGG(gene = mygene,
+                  organism = "aja",
+                  pvalueCutoff = 0.05)
--> No gene can be mapped....
--> Expected input gene ID: 
--> return NULL...